# sql, optimizate mysql request, left join

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this sql query
If in my select i have `user.img` request last 4.5385 second

if i removed `user.img` request last 0.0011

```
SELECT `history`.`id`, `history`.`title`, `history`.`user_id`, `history`.`description`, `history`.`datetime`, `user`.`id` AS `userId`, `user`.`username`, `user`.`img`
FROM `history` 
LEFT JOIN `user` ON history.user_id = user.id 
ORDER BY `id` DESC 
LIMIT 6
```

In history table i have 943535 records

in user table i have 3 users(only 3)

[history table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muXez.png)

[user table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75FlW.png)

how optimiat

Comment: Are the ' 's or the group by needed?  You are not specifining which id you are ordering by either.

Comment: sorry, i remove group by, but the problem exists

Comment: what kind of data type is user.img?

Comment: for user.img varchar 255

Comment: You are sorting rows by a left-joined column that can be null. Is that what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

varchar(255) bits multiplied by 943535 is a few megabytes (20MB+ roughly). And this is where the slowness is coming from. You might not want to call this column. Try to tie that using program code instead.

You probably need to work on your data types and foreign key combinations.

Comment: for images, i must to create new table, user_img , and link picture to users table with fk?

Comment: You can leave it in the user table. But I would not bring it into this query, resulting in a multiplication of that data significantly. I would query the small user table separately and use application code to tie the two tables instead of the sql call.